# How to improve readability of enum JSON file?

Tags: c#, json

I use JSON file to save my game's setting data. There're some `enum` type (Unity project c#) in the data. Right now in the JSON file I use integer to represent `enum` values in the JSON file.

This causes 2 problems.
1, editing the JSON file manually is painful since I can't remember all the `enum` values and I have to go back to the cs file to view which enum means what. (The purpose of using enum is to improve readability in the first place)
2, when I changes the enum class for example insert new values before other old enum values, then the whole JSON file would be wrong.

Is there any tricks to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, always add new enum constants at the end of the enum unless you have a very good reason to otherwise. Doing otherwise you need to migrate the data/settings to match the new order. That should be one problem solved.

Now, you haven't specified which tool you're using to seralize/deserialize your JSON, so I'm giving you an example using JSON.NET. This solution is to serialize the text representation of the enum constant rather than the integer value. Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

```
public enum GameDifficulty
{
    Easy,
    Normal,
    Difficult,
    Insane
}

public class PlayerSettings
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Should convert between the enum value and a string representation in JSON
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public GameDifficulty Difficulty { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere in your code...
var settings = new PlayerSettings
{
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Bob",
    Difficulty = GameDifficulty.Difficult
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
// Prints:
// {
//   "ID": 1,
//   "Name": "Bob",
//   "Difficulty": "Difficult"
// }
```

[See it in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mcnFLM)

Comment: Thank you! I use JsonUtility, which does not even support arbitrary keys in dictionary. By JSON.NET do you mean this? https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347

Comment: @ArtS I'm referring to [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) AKA JSON.NET. For Unity it seems [this port](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity) is the way to go

Comment: Thank you. After testing, it seems you don't event need adding `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`. It just handles to parse the string in the Json file into enum type.